# How to find where the memcached on Mac OS is installed?

Tags: macos, memcached, macports

How to find the location of the installed Memcached server on mac, which is installed using the MacPorts tool?

I want to restart the Memcache server, in verbose mode.

This Memcache server is automatically getting restarted, even though I killed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memcached from MacPorts installs a launchd plist file. If that is loaded, launchd will always restart memcached when it notices it is terminated (this is default launchd behavior).

Use `sudo port load memcached`/`sudo port unload memcached` to activate/deactive this launchd plist.

If the plist is unloaded, you can manually start memcached using the binary. You can find the binary using `port contents memcached | grep -E /s?bin/`.

Comment: thanks for the answer many i know how to find the location where memcached is installed on our mac ?

Comment: See the second part of the answer; `port contents memcached | grep -E '/s?bin/'` will answer that.